# Aggregating observations based on category in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a set of agricultural data in R that looks something like this:

```
    State       District    Year    Crop      Production   Area
1   State A     District 1  2000    Banana    1254.00      2000.00
2   State A     District 1  2000    Apple     175.00       176.00
3   State A     District 1  2000    Wheat     321.00       641.00
4   State A     District 1  2000    Rice      1438.00      175.00
5   State A     District 1  2000    Cashew    154.00       1845.00
6   State A     District 1  2000    Peanut    2076.00      439.00
7   State B     District 2  2000    Banana    3089.00      1987.00
8   State B     District 2  2000    Apple     309.00       302.00
9   State B     District 2  2000    Wheat     401.00       230.00
10  State B     District 2  2000    Rice      1832.00      2134.00
11  State B     District 2  2000    Cashew    991.00       1845.00
12  State B     District 2  2000    Peanut    2311.00      1032.00
```

I want to aggregate the area and production values by crop type, but keep the state, district and year details, so that it would look something like:

```
    State       District    Year    Crop      Production   Area
1   State A     District 1  2000    Fruit     1429.00      2176.00
2   State A     District 1  2000    Grain     1759.00      816.00
3   State A     District 1  2000    Nut       2230.00      2284.00
4   State B     District 2  2000    Fruit     3398.00      2289.00
5   State B     District 2  2000    Grain     2233.00      2364.00
6   State B     District 2  2000    Nut       3302.00      2877.00
```

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Ermmm you need to know how to group the Crop column right? For example, Banana, Apple belows to Fruit, Wheat,Rice to Grain etc.. Where would you have this information?

Comment: If you are recoding the 'Crop' column, you may need to pass a key/value for changing the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` & `forcats`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

df %>%
   mutate(crop_type = fct_recode(Crop, fruit = "Apple", fruit = "Banana",
                                       grain = "Wheat", grain = "Rice",
                                       nut = "Cashew", nut = "Peanut")) %>%
   group_by(State, District, Year, Crop) %>%
   summarize(mean_production = mean(Production),
             mean_area = mean(Area))
```

Comment: Yeah, `case_when()` is also a great option, might save some typing if there's a lot of subcategories!

Comment: This worked! I did end up needing to convert the crop categories from factors to characters for some work later, and I used the sum instead of mean. But the basic idea got me there. Thank you!